# How to save int and string columns in a java array / list?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm reading a SQLite DB in java and have a result-set of an integer type and string type.

The result-set is never the same size, so a string array wouldn't work I believe.

What I have is [Int ItemID] [String ItemName] and want to be able to get the resultset to save these to some sort of map, list or array so that I can output them to the user as called upon.

I attempted the below with a string array; but like I said about - It's never the same size as its a search query against a SQLite DB.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:ItemDB.db");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
String queryResults[][] = null;
while (resultSet.next()) {
    queryResults[current][0] = resultSet.getString("itemId");
    queryResults[current][1] = resultSet.getString("itemName");
    current++;
}
resultSet.close();
statement.close();
connection.close();
return queryResults;
```

If there's a better way to achieve what I'm looking for I'm all ears!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a map:

```
Map<Integer, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    dataMap.put(resultSet.getInt("itemId"), resultSet.getString("itemName"));
}
```

**Edit:** You can use a `TreeMap` if you need the keys to be sorted.

Comment: Awesome! That's what I'm looking for. Is there a way to sort it by Integer after? It takes 1000 and puts it after 1 unfortunately.

Comment: @DotSlashShell use a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

Comment: Order the response in your SQL ("... ORDER BY some_column") and then use a LinkedHashMap vs. HashMap to maintain insertion order.

Comment: TreeMap did it for me!

Comment: FYI, a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) is a [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html), so its keys are kept in sorted order. For more info, [search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+%2BSortedMap+site%3Astackoverflow.com&t=osx&ia=web).

Comment: @DotSlashShell In the future, think through the details when drafting your Question, so you do not need to add such important points later in comments.